# Azure openai speech to text -Whisper "code":"404","message": "Resource not found"

Tags: azure, speech-to-text, openai-api, azure-openai, whisper

i'm trying to transcribe a audio file by using whisper through Azure openai key,endpoints,deployment

eventhough i.m adding right credencials by deploying in valid region for whisper and with their permission granted(Followed each steps)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/whisper-quickstart?tabs=powershell&pivots=programming-language-powershell

**getting this error: Error 404: {"error":{"code":"404","message": "Resource not found"}}
**

tried transcription on azure playground using same deployment its working there

```
import os
import requests

# Azure OpenAI credentials
os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_KEY'] = 'KEY'
os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT'] = 'ENDPOINT'

# Azure OpenAI metadata variables
openai = {
    'api_key': os.environ.get('AZURE_OPENAI_KEY'),
    'api_base': os.environ.get('AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT'),
    'api_version': '2023-06-01-preview',
    'name': 'deployment name'
}

# Header for authentication
headers = {
    'api-key': openai['api_key']
}

# audio file
file_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/speech2text/sampleaudiO.wav'

# URL for the API endpoint
url = f"{openai['api_base']}/openai/deployments/{openai['name']}/audio/transcriptions?api-version={openai['api_version']}"

try:
    # Reading the audio file as binary data
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as audio_file:
        # Send the request to Azure OpenAI for transcription
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files={"file": audio_file})

        # Check if the request was successful and print the transcription
        if response.status_code == 200:
            transcription = response.json().get('text', 'Transcription not available')
            print("Transcription:", transcription)
        else:
            print(f"Error {response.status_code}: {response.text}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
here
```

Please help with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Getting this error: Error 404: {"error":{"code":"404","message": "Resource not found"}}

The above error occurs when you pass the wrong parameters, such as (api_key, api_base, api_version) in your request.

In your request, you have passed the wrong API version. After passing the correct **`api_version=2023-09-01-preview`** in the Python code, it executed successfully in my environment.

**Code:**

```py
import os
import requests

os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_KEY'] = 'xxxx'
os.environ['AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT'] = 'https://resource-name.openai.azure.com'

# Azure OpenAI metadata variables
openai = {
    'api_key': os.environ.get('AZURE_OPENAI_KEY'),
    'api_base': os.environ.get('AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT'),
    'api_version': '2023-09-01-preview',
    'name': 'whisper-deployment'
}

headers = {
    'api-key': openai['api_key']
}

file_path = './harvard.wav'

url = f"{openai['api_base']}/openai/deployments/{openai['name']}/audio/transcriptions?api-version={openai['api_version']}"

try:
    # Reading the audio file as binary data
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as audio_file:
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, files={"file": audio_file})
        if response.status_code == 200:
            transcription = response.json().get('text', 'Transcription not available')
            print("Transcription:", transcription)
        else:
            print(f"Error {response.status_code}: {response.text}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

**Output:**

```
Transcription: The stale smell of old beer lingers. It takes heat to bring out the odor. A cold dip restores health and zest. A salt pickle tastes fine with ham. Tacos al pastor are my favorite. A zestful food is the hot cross bun.
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[Azure OpenAI Service REST API reference - Azure OpenAI | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/reference#request-a-speech-to-text-translation).

Comment: Can you help with getting Timestamp responses or speaker classification

Comment: Please raise new questions with detail information.